# node.js, firebase and authentication

Tags: node.js, firebase

I want to create backend to my application. I'm using node.js and firebase to store data. I have simple login component and I want to authenticate user. When login is pressed, username and password data is sending to server. Can somebody tell me how to make it correct?

```
app.get('/authenticate', (req, res) => {
  const username = req.body.username;
  const password = req.body.password;
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly the architecture you are envisaging is as follows:

Firebase will be the backend of your application (for the database tier and the authentication services, most probably) and node.js will expose the services (e.g. REST APIs) that will be "consumed" by your front end (web app most probably).

In this case, you should use the [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/) to communicate between node.js and the Firebase backend. You would use the `admin.auth` module for the authentication "matters".

*To be complete, note that Firebase offers some dedicated client SDKs (JavaScript/Android/iOS) that allow connecting the front-end directly to the Firebase services.*